# Ideal programming language

Tags: web

I am new to programming but I would like to create a web app.
Basically, I would like to upload an excel file to that app that will use that file, do some calculation and prompt some forms that I will be able to download. I am thinking about a web app because I would like anybody else to be able to create a session and use the app.
Which language should I use please? I attended 2 semesters of c++ and a data structures class.
thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think any Programming Language suitable for web applications can fulfill the requirement with standard library and external modules
Now for the choice, if the calculations are complex and require extensive Math and Statistic Libraries Python would be ideal ( With Flask or Django for exposing functionalities As a web app)
Otherwise, a light and Cloud-Native language such as Golang would be also nice.

Comment: thank you . The calculs are not complex at all. So i will learn Go then